# Parachutist and Differential Equations Modeling Air Reistance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A parachutist whose mass is  65 kg drops from a helicopter hovering 2500 m above the ground and falls toward the ground under the influence of gravity. Assume that the force due to air resistance is proportional to the velocity of the​ parachutist, with the proportionality constant $b_1$= 20 ​N-sec/m when the chute is closed and  ​$b_2$= 90 N-sec/m when the chute is open. If the chute does not open until the velocity of the parachutist reaches  ​m/sec, after how many seconds will the parachutist reach the​ ground? Assume that the acceleration due to gravity is $9.81 m/s^2$.

The answer is apparently 345.06 seconds.

In my work, the subscripts 1 and 2 represent the quantities they are attached to before and after the chute is opened, respectively. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

$$\sum F_{1}=mg-b_1v_1=m\frac{dv_1}{dt}$$

$$\frac{dv_1}{dt}=g-\frac{b_1}{m}v_1;\frac{b_1}{m}=c_1=\frac{4}{13}$$

$$\int_{0}^{v}\frac{dv_1}{g-c_1v_1}=\int_{o}^{t_1}dt;c_1=\frac{b_1}{m}\Rightarrow -\frac{ln(g-c_1v_1)}{c_1}=-\frac{ln(g-c_1v_1)}{c_1}+\frac{ln(g)}{c_1}=t_1$$

$$ln(\frac{g}{g-c_1v_1})=c_1t\Rightarrow e^{c_1t}=\frac{g}{g-c_1v_1}\Rightarrow v_1=-\frac{g}{c_1e^{c_1t}}+\frac{g}{c_1}=-\frac{9.81}{\frac{4}{13}e^{\frac{4}{13}t}}+\frac{9.81}{\frac{4}{13}}$$

$$v_1(t)=\frac{dx_1}{dt}=-31.885e^{-\frac{4}{13}t}+31.8825$$

$$\sum F_2=m\frac{dv_2}{dt}=mg-b_2v_2$$

$$\frac{dv_2}{dt}=g-\frac{b_2}{m}v_2;\frac{b_2}{m}=c_2=\frac{18}{13}$$

$$\int_{25}^{v}=\frac{dv}{g-c_2v_2}=\int_{0}^{t_2}dt\Rightarrow -\frac{ln(g-c_2v_2)}{c_2}+\frac{ln(g-25c_2)}{c_2}=t_2$$

$$v_2(t)=17.915e^{-\frac{18}{13}}+7.085$$

From

$$x(t)=m\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2}=mg-b_2\frac{dx_2}{dt}$$

I have

$$\frac{m(gt-v)}{b}+C=\frac{m(gt-(17.915e^{-\frac{18}{13}}+7.085))}{b}+C$$

Comment: The physics is pretty simple, but maybe more appropriate for physics site.

Comment: Dont cross post; you will end up wasting peoples time; question was posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/610008/parachuting-and-air-resistance-modeled-with-differential-equations

Comment: There is a number missing in "velocity of the parachutist reaches ​m/sec".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just take the general ODE $v'=g-cv$, set $u=g-cv$, find $u'=-cu$ so that $u(t)=e^{-ct}u_0$ and substitute back for $v$.
$$
(g-cv(t))=e^{-ct}(g-cv(0))\implies v(t)=v(0)e^{-ct}+(1-e^{-ct})\frac{g}{c}
$$
Then insert the values for both phases, with $v_1(0)=0$. This shortens the computation considerably and thus reduces the probability of errors.

Next compute the time $t_o$ of the parachute opening, that is, solve $v_1(t)=v_o$ or
$$
e^{-c_1t_o}=\frac{g-c_1v_1(t_o)}{g-c_1v_1(0)}\iff
t_o=\frac{-\ln(1-\frac{c_1v_o}{g})}{c_1}
$$
Then apply the general equation with shifted origin to the second phase for initial condition $v_2(t_o)=v_o$
$$
g-cv_2(t)=e^{-c_2(t-t_c)}(g-c_2v_2(t_o))
\implies v(t_2)=v_oe^{-c_2(t-t_o)}+(1-e^{-c(t-t_o)})\frac{g}{c_2}
$$
To compute the distance to the ground you need to integrate the velocity
$$
v_1(t) = (1-e^{-c_1t})\frac{g}{c_1}\implies x_1(t)=(e^{-c_1t}-1+c_1t)\frac{g}{c_1^2}
$$
Then integrate $v_2$ with $x_2(t_o)=x_1(t_o)=(e^{-c_1t_o}-1+c_1t_o)\frac{g}{c_1^2}$.